# Can this JavaScript be optimized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, refactoring

This JS will be executed on pages with a lot of fields. Can you see anyway to improve the speed of this code? If so, can you explain what you found?

```
var _TextInputs = null;
function GetTextInputs()
{
    if (_TextInputs == null)
    {
        _TextInputs = jq('input[type=text]');
    }

    return _TextInputs;
}

var _Spans = null;
function GetSpans()
{
    if (_Spans == null)
    {
        _Spans = jq('span');
    }

    return _Spans;
}


function UpdateRate(ratefield, name)
{
    GetTextInputs().filter('[' + name + ']').each(function()
    {
        this.value = FormatCurrencyAsString(FormatCurrencyAsFloat(ratefield.value));
        CalculateCharge(name.replace('Rate', ''), jq(this).attr(name));
    });
}

function CalculateCharge(name, activity_id)
{
    var inputs = GetTextInputs();
    var bill_field = inputs.filter('[' + name + 'Bill=' + activity_id + ']');
    var rate_field = inputs.filter('[' + name + 'Rate=' + activity_id + ']');
    var charge_field = GetSpans().filter('[' + name + 'Charge=' + activity_id + ']'); 

    charge_field.text(FormatCurrencyAsString(FormatCurrencyAsFloat(bill_field.val()) * FormatCurrencyAsFloat(rate_field.val())));
}
```

Comment: Firebug has a great javascript profiler.  That will show you where the time is actually being spent.

Comment: Firefox executes this very quick. The problem is with IE.

Comment: IE 8 also has a great JavaScript profiler built in. Press F12.

Comment: @harpo: If you throw up an answer I'll give it to you. Your comment was way more helpful then you probably thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

- Replace `each` with `while`
- Replace `val()` with `.value` (should be fine as long as those fields are plain text ones)
- Access elements by class instead of by name/type
- Replace `attr()` with plain property access; e.g.: `this.attr(name)` --> `this.name`

These are all rather unobtrusive changes which should speed things up mainly due to cutting down on function calls.

Don't query elements on every function call **if those elements are static** (i.e. are not modified during your app life-cycle). Instead, store them outside the loop.

Comment: Between the Firebug profiler and some (in retrospect) obvious temporary variables I did manage to make this code "snappier".
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I can see that you're using attribute filters everywhere, e.g.:

```
_TextInputs = jq('input[type=text]');

inputs.filter('[' + name + 'Bill=' + activity_id + ']');
```

Attribute filters are useful, but not especially 'snappy' when compared to more direct class or ID selectors. I can't see any markup so the best I can do is suggest that you use more IDs and classes, e.g.:

```
jq('input.textInput');
```

instead of:

```
jq('input[type=text]');
```

Answer (score 0):

A little off-topic, but I use and recommend [Javascript Rocks](http://javascriptrocks.com/performance/). This books contains a TON of awesome JS optimisation advice by the creator of Scriptaculous. Also comes with a tool called DOM Monster which helps track down performance bottlenecks - it's an awesome compliment to Firebug as it actually tracks through the DOM looking for inefficiencies based on heuristics and DOM complexity.